# What should one do if one works on a problem and submits a paper only to find that it is already in some book?

Tags: soft-question, advice

What should one do if one works on a problem and submits a paper only to find from the editor, that the work is already in some book?
The work is is not really easy to find on the internet and was therefore missed to be noticed. But since a lot of hard work has been put in, what can one do?

Comment: Life can throw nasty surprises at u at times, son. U can only pick yourself up and get on with life

Comment: One can be proud that one constructed, on one's own, a proof that happened to already been constructed and published by another. That you weren't the *first* doesn't have to diminish that sense of accomplishment.

Comment: @Math, AM: as Forrest Gump would say: s..t happens, and if you didn't notice then the editor will tell you (or not), but if you found out *before* submiting the paper then stop and try to make some ammendments so that you'll paper, together with the existing one(s), can apport a new thing...

Comment: Is it the exact same proof? I know of tons of published papers called things like "A New Proof of ... "

Comment: This seems to me more appropriate for academia.se.

Comment: @ amWhy: Thanks a lot for the encouragement. Is there a way of getting the work seen without it being published, but still  acknowledging the fact that a book already covers it.

Comment: @Matt It is not the exact same proof. Mine is more intuitive and pictorial than the one in the book.

Comment: @MathAM You could paper to write a review if the path you took if your work is essentially different from the work done in the book.